# The best cable organizing solution for the servers on the rails?

Tags: hardware, rack, cable

I'm looking for the best cable organizing solution for the servers installed on the rails inside a rack as well as for the equipment on the rollout carts.

I believe there should be some foldable cable holders like rackmount KVMs have - the elbow should be similar like the elbow of the door closer. But can't find any existing solutions on the market. Can you point me to the right direction please?

Comment: found an answer - it's called "cable management arm"

Comment: When you buy rack mounting kits you need to ensure you get ALL the required parts, which includes the cable arm.

Comment: Your question is different enough not to close as duplicate, but the following questions might help you further: http://serverfault.com/questions/25985/to-use-cable-management-arms-or-not or http://serverfault.com/questions/1473/cable-management-policy or http://serverfault.com/questions/26462/how-do-you-organise-the-cables-in-your-racks

Comment: 2jg: unfortunately usually the kit includes only a rails.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the servers we buy have sliding rails and come with cable management cages that attach to the back of the server so that once you route all your cables through them, you can slide the server out without disconnecting anything.

For everything else, there are plastic zip ties or hook+loop (velcro) strips.  The rack enclosures we have also generally have cable routing areas on the back corners of each enclosure.

Answer (score 1):

Both Dell and HP have server cable managment products however they only work with thier respective servers. These products work very well and are hands down the best out there. For a more general solution I have used thin wall felexable conduit for a few odd ball devices. This works well enough but not great.

Answer (score 0):

in a pinch I've just used velcro straps and hang the cables that way.  But that's based on the assumption that I won't be pulling out a server much once it's in there.  To allow easy sliding in and out you can get one of those cable management shelves. Check with the server's hardware manufacturer.